# Align anchored widgets to fill whitespace in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-constraintlayout, spacing

I am new at Android development and I am struggling with the following.
I am building a simple calculator application with a 4x4 keypad.
All the buttons are anchored from right to left and bottom to top. Baselines are used as well.
The top-left button will be anchored to the TextView above.
I need the buttons to keep the square size I gave them, but also be aligned properly so they fill the white space remaining to the right.
I tried anchoring the right side of the right-edge button to the right side of the TextView, but the intermediate column spacing is not divided in equal portions.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="numberSigned|number|numberDecimal"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtNewNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtResult" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtNewNumber"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtNewNumber" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="2"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btn1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="3"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btn2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="4"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btn1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn5"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="5"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btn4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn6"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="6"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btn5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn7"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="8"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btn8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn8"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btn4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn9"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="9"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btn7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPlus"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btn3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMinus"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btn6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMultiply"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="*"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btn9"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDot"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="."
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btn8"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn0"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btnDot"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnDot" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEquals"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="="
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btn0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDivision"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="/"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btnEquals"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnEquals" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to post the XML for your layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To spread out the buttons like you want, you can use *ConstraintLayout* [CHAIN_SPREAD_INSIDE chains](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#Chains).

Here is your XML with the first row placed into a horizontal chain. See how the views spread out between the leftmost and rightmost anchor points? (I have set the rightmost anchor to the end of the result view.)

[image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="numberSigned|number|numberDecimal"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtNewNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtResult" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btn2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtNewNumber"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtNewNumber"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="2"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btn1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btn3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="3"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btn2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btnPlus"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPlus"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btn3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/txtResult"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="4"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btn1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn5"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="5"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btn4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn6"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="6"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btn5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn7"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="8"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btn8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn8"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btn4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn9"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="9"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btn7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMinus"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btn6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMultiply"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="*"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btn9"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDot"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="."
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btn8"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn0"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btnDot"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnDot" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEquals"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="="
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btn0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDivision"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="/"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btnEquals"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnEquals" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The other rows will work the same way.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I have been trying to accomplish.